# What would be the most efficient way to parse the input from a specific column into separate columns?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, parsing

I have a CSV file with a specific column Message with the following input inside of it that I would like to separate out properly. Please be aware that that snippet below does not look like this in Excel where I currently need it to be formatted for

```
    ["CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
Request for API: /api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment Caller:C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1 RequestedSchemas: {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy, {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,  TenantId: 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5"]
```

I would like to separate it out so that it will look like this.(The names of the column will be before the colon and the information inside of it will be what is after the colon.)

```
CorrelationID: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9
Request for API: 
/api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment
Caller:C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1
RequestedSchemas: {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy, {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,
TenantId: 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5[![enter image description here]
```

I have tried using the text-to-columns but in Excel but it does not come out correctly

What I would like to know what is the best way to do this is. I am currently making a program in C# to try and parse it out properly but what I have does not work correctly.

For any reference here is my C# code. However I am open to any way of doing this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\Users\t-maucal\Desktop\MachineLearningTestSets\CSVParse.csv"))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(" ");
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                //Process row
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                foreach (string field in fields)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(field);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Message Column RAW FORMAT]
[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

Comment: @Bridgitte1Trick What are you getting as your results via your code?

Comment: How you would distinct between previous value and name of next value? ": b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9 Request for API:"

Comment: @Fabio the column names are CorrelationID, Request For Api, Caller, Requested Schema and Tenant ID

Comment: Then search for the column names in that string (including the colon) and extract the column values from the string. You know the content for each column starts right behind its column name (incl. the colon) and it ends right before the next column name found.

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking to do that the answers to your last post did not do. What does this mean?: "The names of the column will be before the colon and the information inside of it will be what is after the colon." Can you include a better illustration of what you expect the spreadsheet to look like?

Comment: @Luck I have added pictures now

Comment: You can parse this fairly easily with VBA and Regular Expressions. I imagine you could also do that in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Macro written in VBA.

I created a Class and renamed it `cData` with properties of your different column headings.

Then I used Regular Expressions to separate the different properties from the data you provided, collected it into a Dictionary, and output the results to a separate worksheet in a specified order.

I assumed that your named column headers were the information you are looking for, and, as in your text example, there is only a single instance of each category to be concerned with.

I also assumed that your data starts in `B1`.

Read the notes closely in the macro.

Be sure to set the references as indicated in the Regular Module Code.

**Class Module**

```
'Rename this Module **cData**
Option Explicit
Private pCorrelationID As String
Private pRequestForApi As String
Private pCaller As String
Private pRequestedSchemas As String
Private pTenantID As String

Public Property Get CorrelationID() As String
    CorrelationID = pCorrelationID
End Property
Public Property Let CorrelationID(Value As String)
    pCorrelationID = Value
End Property

Public Property Get RequestForApi() As String
    RequestForApi = pRequestForApi
End Property
Public Property Let RequestForApi(Value As String)
    pRequestForApi = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Caller() As String
    Caller = pCaller
End Property
Public Property Let Caller(Value As String)
    pCaller = Value
End Property

Public Property Get RequestedSchemas() As String
    RequestedSchemas = pRequestedSchemas
End Property
Public Property Let RequestedSchemas(Value As String)
    pRequestedSchemas = Value
End Property

Public Property Get TenantID() As String
    TenantID = pTenantID
End Property
Public Property Let TenantID(Value As String)
    pTenantID = Value
End Property
```

**Regular Module**

```
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'Set Reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Option Explicit
Sub ttcSpecial()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim rRes As Range
    Dim dD As Dictionary
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection, M As Match
    Dim cD As cData
    Dim myKey, I As Long, sTemp As String

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    If Not IsArray(vSrc) Then
        sTemp = vSrc
        ReDim vSrc(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        vSrc(1, 1) = sTemp
    End If
End With

Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .Pattern = "((?:CorrelationID|Request For API|Caller|RequestedSchemas|TenantID)):([\s\S]+?)(?=(?:CorrelationID|Request For API|Caller|RequestedSchemas|TenantID|$))"
End With


Set dD = New Dictionary
    dD.CompareMode = TextCompare

For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cD = New cData
    With cD
    If RE.Test(vSrc(I, 1)) = True Then
        myKey = I
        Set MC = RE.Execute(vSrc(I, 1))
        For Each M In MC
            Select Case M.SubMatches(0)
                Case "CorrelationID"
                    .CorrelationID = M.SubMatches(1)
                Case "Request for API"
                    .RequestForApi = M.SubMatches(1)
                Case "Caller"
                    .Caller = M.SubMatches(1)
                Case "RequestedSchemas"
                    .RequestedSchemas = M.SubMatches(1)
                Case "TenantID"
                    .TenantID = M.SubMatches(1)
            End Select
        Next M

        dD.Add Key:=myKey, Item:=cD
    End If
    End With
Next I

ReDim vRes(0 To dD.Count, 1 To 5)

'Headers
    vRes(0, 1) = "Correlation ID"
    vRes(0, 2) = "Request for API"
    vRes(0, 3) = "Caller"
    vRes(0, 4) = "Requested Schemas"
    vRes(0, 5) = "Tenant ID"

I = 0
For Each myKey In dD.Keys
    I = I + 1
    With dD(myKey)
        vRes(I, 1) = .CorrelationID
        vRes(I, 2) = .RequestForApi
        vRes(I, 3) = .Caller
        vRes(I, 4) = .RequestedSchemas
        vRes(I, 5) = .TenantID
    End With
Next myKey

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

**Results from text sample in original question**

[image]

**The Regex** *simplified explanation*

- Match any of the Column Headers
- Match everything that starts after the Colon

  - up to but NOT including another Column Header, or the end of the string

Comment: I have never used VBA before. Can you explain how to use this

Comment: @Brigitte1Trick There's plenty of information on SO, and I'm sure you can replicate the steps in `C#`.  But briefly, To enter this Macro (Sub), `alt-F11` opens the Visual Basic Editor. Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and paste the code below into the window that opens.  You'll do something similar with the `Class Module` and rename it using the `Properties` window.
To use this Macro (Sub), `alt-F8` opens the macro dialog box. Select the macro by name, and **RUN**.

Comment: @Brigitte1Trick Be sure to carefully read the code so you understand it, and can adapt it to your specific situation.

Comment: Comile Error: User defined type not defined (Dim dD AS Dictionary) @Ron Rosenfield do you know what it means?

Comment: @Brigitte1Trick What line?

Comment: Rosenfield 4 and 8

Comment: @Brigitte1Trick Not helpful since no line has a number.  But most likely, you didn't set the references as instructed in the notes; and/or you didn't rename the class module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195880/discussion-between-brigitte1trick-and-ron-rosenfeld).

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of error-prone work.  Just use [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) by Josh Close.  It's an excellent package that's fast and easy to use.

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you showed how to apply `CSVHelper` to the data.  I'm not sure how to do that since the data is not in a `CSV` format.

Answer (score 0):

Using formulas, @cybernetic.nomad had it most of the way there. In order to remove the titles from the data you can try these:

1. Put the categories of each column (CorrelationId:, Request for API:) in cells `B1:G1`
2. in `B2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =RIGHT(LEFT($A2,FIND(C$1,$A2)-1),LEN(LEFT($A2,FIND(C$1,$A2)-1))-(LEN(B1)+2))
   ```
3. in `C2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =RIGHT(MID($A2,FIND(C$1,$A2),FIND(D$1,$A2,FIND(C$1,$A2))-FIND(C$1,$A2)),LEN(MID($A2,FIND(C$1,$A2),FIND(D$1,$A2,FIND(C$1,$A2))-FIND(C$1,$A2)))-(LEN(C1)+1))
   ```
4. in `D2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =RIGHT(MID($A2,FIND(D$1,$A2),FIND(E$1,$A2,FIND(D$1,$A2))-FIND(D$1,$A2)),LEN(MID($A2,FIND(D$1,$A2),FIND(E$1,$A2,FIND(D$1,$A2))-FIND(D$1,$A2)))-(LEN(D1)+2))
   ```
5. in `E2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =RIGHT(MID($A2,FIND(E$1,$A2),FIND(F$1,$A2,FIND(E$1,$A2))-FIND(E$1,$A2,FIND(D$1,$A2))-1),LEN(MID($A2,FIND(E$1,$A2),FIND(F$1,$A2,FIND(E$1,$A2))-FIND(E$1,$A2,FIND(D$1,$A2))))-(LEN(E1)+2))
   ```
6. in `F2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =RIGHT(MID($A2,FIND(F$1,$A2),FIND(G$1,$A2,FIND(F$1,$A2))-FIND(F$1,$A2)),LEN(MID($A2,FIND(F$1,$A2),FIND(G$1,$A2,FIND(F$1,$A2))-FIND(F$1,$A2)))-(LEN(F1)+2))
   ```
7. in `G2`, use the following formula:

   ```
   =RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(G$1,$A2)-LEN(G1))
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Not sure why but it gives me #VALUE? in all the ones except the 1st formula column. do you know why @Luck